# Photo preview is different from the picture

Tags: android, android-camera

I am doing a simple application using Camera android and noticed that when a take a picture, the preview camera image is a little smaller than the final picture. What am I doing wrong?

attached example images from the app:

[image: the preview image]

[image: and here the final image]

Comment: What makes you think that you are doing something wrong? The preview frames do not have to have the same aspect ratio as do the final images.

Comment: the aspect of the images are too different. I want a result like instagram app

Comment: Then you have to choose preview and picture aspect ratios that you like. You are the one, in your code, who is choosing the preview resolution (among the available options) and is choosing the picture resolution (among the available options). You will need to adjust your algorithms for choosing those to take aspect ratio into account.

Comment: On some devices, choosing picture size and preview size with different  aspect ratios results in even more weird pictures. I recommend to always keep the two sizes in sync.